# pass customobject as argument from objective C to c++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

In my app I am calling a `c++` function from `objective-c` which takes arguments as key values `pair<String:String>`.

I am able to pass pair of `std::map<std::string, std::string> args` successfully but now I want to pass a dictionary.

I have try to google it but I am unable to understand it.

For better understanding here is my code:

```
+(void)createChatRoom:(NSDictionary *)chatRoomInfo forCompanyJSON:(NSDictionary *)companyJsonString completion:(void(^)(BOOL))completionHandler
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        @autoreleasepool{
            NSString *strOwner = [chatRoomInfo objectForKey:@"owner"];
            NSString *strCreator = [chatRoomInfo objectForKey:@"creator"];
            NSString *strSubject = [chatRoomInfo objectForKey:@"subject"];
            NSString *strProfilePic = [chatRoomInfo objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
            NSInteger isPublic = [[chatRoomInfo objectForKey:@"isPublic"]boolValue] ? 1 :0;
            NSString *strDescription = [chatRoomInfo objectForKey:@"description"];
            NSString *strStatus = [chatRoomInfo objectForKey:@"status"];

            std::map<std::string, std::string> args;
            args["owner"] = std::string([strOwner UTF8String]);
            args["creator"] = std::string([strCreator UTF8String]);
            args["subject"] = std::string([strSubject UTF8String]);
            args["profilePic"] = std::string([strProfilePic UTF8String]);
            args["isPublic"] = isPublic;
            args["description"] = std::string([strDescription UTF8String]);
            args["status"] = std::string([strStatus UTF8String]);
            args["company"] = **//Here i want to pass dictonary**

            //Code to set the Log file path for iOS app, to avoid the crash on Logger
            //Code to call the web service
            WS::Response resp = WS::createRoom(args);

            //Print the web service response in console window
            NSString *response_body = [NSString stringWithCString:resp.body.c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
            NSLog(@"%@", response_body);
            NSLog(@"Response fetched successfully");
        }
    });
}
```

Any help or suggetion will be helpful to me.

Comment: Convert your dictionary to a json string and pass it normally like a std::string. When you want to get dictionary to use, convert json string to dictionary.

Comment: But i want to pass object , is there any way like we do  with "id" in objectve c or "any" in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve it, you have to declare `args` as `std::map<std::string, id>`.

```
std::map<std::string, id> args;
args["owner"] = strOwner;
args["creator"] = strCreator;
args["subject"] = strSubject;
args["profilePic"] = strProfilePic;
args["isPublic"] = @(isPublic);
args["description"] = strDescription;
args["status"] = strStatus;
args["company"] = [NSDictionary new];
```

Comment: Thanks man. it seems working but line  args["isPublic"] = @isPublic; giving error for @

Comment: My bad, it should be `@(isPublic)` instead of `@isPublic`. Updated my answer.

Comment: got it.Thanks again(: